# Store files in google drive from Google App Engine

Tags: java, google-app-engine, google-drive-api

All,
I have a google application engine (java) that requires to store some images. I tried using Blobs and storing them in datastore but as you know there is a size limit on data that can be stored in datastore.
So as result I'm storing the images on a different server and store the path in my datastore and all works fine.
Now I'm thinking on using a google drive folder instead of using a server to upload the files to the drive and using the share link to display them later.
I've seen https://developers.google.com/drive/web/quickstart/java and got it to work fine. When I try to use it in my application however obviously this won't work as the code is assuming a credential for a local user.
I created a service key on my application and want to change the sample code above to use it but I'm not sure if that's the correct approach.
Tried searching for samples but can't find anyone that takes the same approach. Is there a working sample that shows how to authenticate an application not a user and let's say store a file in google drive?

I've also seen https://developers.google.com/drive/web/examples/ please note what I want is to store files in my google drive and not the user's google drive. So if user A and user B come to my app, they shouldn't have to authorize my application and should both be able to upload a file to my google drive.
I don't know if this can be done directly from their browser or I have to move the file to my application (appspot) and then push it to google drive.

Thanks

Comment: Would it not be easier to use [Google Cloud Storage](https://cloud.google.com/storage/docs/overview)?

Comment: Yes but you have to pay for that. I was hoping by taking advantage of Google drive I won't have to pay for storing the files.

Comment: you could make the picture files in Google Drive public, then you could just link to the drive url. If you don't want that, use the api, which requires an oauth token (https://developers.google.com/identity/protocols/OAuth2)

Comment: The question is how to add the photos to drive not how to link to them. I like the users to upload their images to my google drive.